# best way to style a 14 person staff directory in one page

Tags: page-layout, composition

i'm doing a 14 person staff directory for a corporate souvenir program.

it has to be done on one-page of 190 (w) x 270 (h).

the arrangement is in alphabetical so no hierarchy between positions.

the best i could come up with is:

---

|-|x|x|-|

|x|x|x|x|

|x|x|x|x|

|x|x|x|x|

---

any other way to style it?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try something like this.

```
 X X X
X X X X
 X X X
X X X X
```

or simply

```
X X X X
X X X X
X X X X
X X
```

```
X X X
X X X
X X X
X X X
X X
```

Try all the alternatives you get and check which one suits best to your design.

Comment: +1. Quite sure the god of symmetry is greatly pleased! All hail to symmetry!

Answer (score 0):

The layout you are proposing might suggest a hierarchical structure with the top two people being superiors to those placed below them. Even if the pictures will be in alphabetical order, the first impression will be that the two people on top are somehow special.

Perhaps rotate the your composition by 180 degrees to get something like this:

X X X X

X X X X

X X X X

_ X X _

Placing pictures in this fashion might help to make the impression that everyone is equal.

Answer (score 0):

This may work (a sort of round affair) but depends if you are having a lot of text with the pictures.

```
    X X X
  X   X   X
    X   X
  X   X   X
    X X X
```

Also remember pictures do not have to be in rectangles or squares so try this with a honeycomb structure. It locks together nicely.

Otherwise how about a Wheel with the pictures as an outer circle of circles and a line of text as a spoke.

You do not say what industry you are involved with for this so maybe there is something you can use as inspiration there?  For example IT - Pictures attached to keyboard keys.  Depends how serious this has to look - you say corporate so I suspect serious.